# Unequal Data for Model Compare in R

Tags: r, regression

I'm fairly new to R and am trying to compare two models with the modelCompare function. However, the data set that I am working with is a bit large and has unevenly distributed missing values. When I try the following code for example:

```
Model_A <- lm(DV~var1*var2 + cont.var, data=df)
Model_C <- lm(DV~ cont.var, data=df)
modelCompare(Model_C,Model_A)
```

I get an error that the models have different N values and cannot be compared because data is differentially omitted between the two models. Is there an easy way to remove this variation, as I will be running a number of regression analyses with this data set?

Answer (score 0):

What are you looking to compare? If you want to compare intercepts between the models just:

```
Model_A
Model_C
```

If you want to compare accuracy of the model, use a training and testing dataset!